# Django Model field needs to be unique over multiple models with shared abstract base class

Tags: python, django

Suppose I want to have multiple kinds of articles, all reachable on site.com/news/article-slug
(so depending on article-slug, it can be a video article, a text article, an image slider article, ...)

I have these models:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)

class TextArticle(Article):
    content = models.TextField()

class VideoArticle(Article):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
```

But the problem is that I can create a TextArticle and a VideoArticle with the same slug.

Is there an easy way to fix it so that if there's already a VideoArticle with a specific slug, no TextArticle can be added with the same slug (and vice versa)?

If there's no easy fix:

- should I go for custom form validation with database querying?
- should I not make the base class abstract?
- any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't actually want an abstract class, but rather for the Article class to be the table for which all subclasses reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Comment: Or, if they are all to point to the same table, use a proxy model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just not having an abstract baseclass solved it indeed :)